# Remove non-alphabet characters, convert to lowercase, and remove words smaller than 3 letters for a list of lists

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7 and I'm wondering if I can do many things at once with one line of code.

What I have currently:

```
csvarticles = [['[Beta-blockers]', 'Magic!', '1980', 'Presse medicale'],['Hypertension in the pregnant woman].', '', '2010', 'Medical'],['Arterial hypertension.', '', '1920', 'La Nouvelle']]    
output =  [[re.sub("[^ '\w]"," ",x).strip().lower() for x in y] for y in csvarticles]
output = [[re.sub(r'\b\w{,3}\b','',x) for x in y] for y in output]
>>> [['beta blockers', 'magic', '1980', 'presse medicale'], ['hypertension   pregnant woman', '', '2010', 'medical'], ['arterial hypertension', '', '1920', ' nouvelle']]
```

This is the output I want, but with extra spaces. I'm not really worried about the extra spaces (unless it's an easy fix). Is there any way I could combine these two one-liners?

What I've tried:

```
output =  [[re.sub("[^ '\w{,3}]"," ",x).strip().lower() for x in y] for y in csvarticles]
>>> [['beta blockers', 'magic', '1980', 'presse medicale'], ['hypertension in the pregnant woman', '', '2010', 'medical'], ['arterial hypertension', '', '1920', 'la nouvelle']]

output =  [[re.sub("[r '\b\w{,3}\b]"," ",x).strip().lower() for x in y] for y in csvarticles]
>>> [['[    -        ]', '!', '', ''], ['].', '', '', ''], ['.', '', '', '']]
```

Thanks to @'rahlf23' & @'Jean-François Fabre' for solving my first question. I've read through the documentation for regex and I just can't wrap my mind around it.

Comment: You may try `r"[^ '\w]|\b\w{0,3}\b"`

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor Stribizew. Your suggestion does work (and seems consistently faster) but adds many more spaces than the selected solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No extra spaces if you change your second regex to [`\b\w{1,3}\s`](https://regex101.com/r/yppFED/2)

```
output = [[re.sub(r'\b\w{1,3} ', '', re.sub("[^ '\w]", ' ', item)).strip().lower() for item in row] for row in csvarticles]
```

Output:

```
[['beta blockers', 'magic', '1980', 'presse medicale'], ['hypertension pregnant woman', '', '2010', 'medical'], ['arterial hypertension', '', '1920', 'nouvelle']]
```

Comment: Above and beyond! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
csvarticles = [['[Beta-blockers]', 'Magic!', '1980', 'Presse medicale'],['Hypertension in the pregnant woman].', '', '2010', 'Medical'],['Arterial hypertension.', '', '1920', 'La Nouvelle']]    
new_data = [[re.sub(r'^\s+|\s+$', '', re.sub(r'\W+|\b\w{,3}\b', ' ', x)).lower() for x in i] for i in csvarticles]
```

Output:

```
[['beta blockers', 'magic', '1980', 'presse medicale'], ['hypertension     pregnant woman', '', '2010', 'medical'], ['arterial hypertension', '', '1920', 'nouvelle']]
```

Comment: Amazing, Thank you so much!